# Component-wise Product of all Column Combinations of two Matrices

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-einsum, hstack

As the title says I want to calculate the component-wise product of all column combinations of two matrices. I already found a solution using `numpy.einsum` and `numpy.hstack`. I wonder if there is a solution without `hstack`.

Let `a = [a_1, a_2, ..., a_n]` be a `d x n` matrix and `b = [b_1, b_2, ..., b_m]` a `d x m` matrix. I want to calculate

`[a_1b_1, a_1b_2, ..., a_nb_{n-1}, a_nb_n]`,

where `a_kb_l` is the component wise product, i.e.  `a_kb_l = [a_{1,k}*b{1,l}, ..., a_{d,k}*b{d,l}].T`.

My solution is the following.
`np.hstack(np.einsum('...j,...l -> j...l', a, b))`

Can I go without the `h_stack`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following improvement replaces the `hstack` with a call of `reshape`. This releases quite a bit memory pressure when `d` is high.

`np.einsum('...j,...l -> ...jl', a, b).reshape(d, -1)`